# Build/refresh on multiple simulators at once with Xcode 9 with a single build?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

Xcode 9 supports multiple simulators. That's great! I can choose the simulator, click run, choose another one, click run, and see both simulators open.

Is there a away that I can 'refresh' all open simulators when building and running? Say I have an iPhone X and a iPhone 7 simulator open. I want to be able to do something ala 1) have two simulators open and running. 2) Click Run 3) See both simulators refresh and update.

Comment: If this can be happen, then I am thinking about writing UI test for a messaging app with running two simulators at the same time... So did you find anything ??

Answer (score 0):

Till now , its not possible to debug in both simulators at the same time. You can only check UI , if you add a new simulator the instance of previous will be ended